# BirthDay Wizard Program

Tags: java

1. Given a person’s age, build a Birthday Wizard that can compute the year of birth, considering that you ask the person's age today. Write statements that can be used in a Java program to perform this computation for the Birthday Wizard.

Here what I needed up but it doesn't work. could someone point what I am doing wrong :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Birthday
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
      int birthday;
      int age;
      int YearOfBirth;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in);
      System.out.println(" What is your +Age ?");

      age = keyboard.nextInt();
      YearOfBirth= 2011 - age;
      System.out.println("I was born :+ YearsOfBirth.");
  }
}
```

Comment: What's not working? (Besides the fact that the program requested is literally impossible to implement)

Comment: You may also want to use the Date/Calendar APIs to get the current year.  Otherwise your code won't work in 2012  :-D

Comment: (without knowing someone's birthday, just knowing their age doesn't tell what year they're born, although you can guess with accuracy that increases as the current date gets further from july 1)

Comment: `YearOfBirth` should probably be `yearOfBirth` since it's an int (though I know this isn't the problem)

Comment: if youhave gotten your answer accept the answer that has helped you.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("I was born :+ YearsOfBirth.");
```

You never close your quote before showing yearsOfBirth

```
System.out.println("I was born : "+ YearsOfBirth+".");
```

Try that and let me know.

Also I just noticed you variable names are wrong: in the print statement its `YearsOfBirth` when you declare it it's `YearOfbirth`.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("I was born :+ YearsOfBirth.");
```

Should be

```
System.out.println("I was born :" + YearOfBirth + ".");
```

Don't know if the `age = keyboard.nextInt();` will work though.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("I was born :+ YearsOfBirth."); ......this is wrong

use this :

System.out.println("I was born :+" YearsOfBirth);

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println("I was born :+ YearsOfBirth.");`

This results in the String literal "I was born :+ YearsOfBirth." being printed out. It's not quite what you want. Perhaps this, is what you meant:

`System.out.println("I was born :"+ YearsOfBirth);`

This time, the variable `YearsOfBirth` is converted to a String and concatenated with "I was born :" to provide the desired result.

In Java, when ever you apply the concatenation operator (+) on two objects, and one of them happens to be a String, then the other will be converted to a String object (the value might not make sense), and a new String object will be returned. Also, literals in double-quotes are often Strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Birthday
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
  int birthday;
  int age;
  int yearOfBirth;

  System.out.println(" What is your Age ?");

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in);
  String input = keyboard.nextLine();
  age = Integer.parseInt(input);

  yearOfBirth = 2011 - age;
  System.out.println("I was born :" + yearOfBirth);
  }
}
```

This should work.